# Fourier series of a complex fucntion

Tags: fourier-series

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and let $f(x)=e^{i \pi zx}$ for $x \in (-1,1)$. Extend $f$ on the real line with period $2$. I have to compute its Fourier series and deduce that 
$$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)} = \sum_{k\ \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{(z-k)^2}$$

The Fourier coefficients are
$$\widehat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} e^{i\pi zx} e^{-i\pi k x}dx = \frac{e^{i\pi (z-k)}-e^{-i\pi (z-k)}}{2i\pi(z-k)}=(-1)^k\frac{e^{i\pi z}-e^{-i\pi z}}{2i\pi(z-k)}=(-1)^k\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi(z-k)}$$

Hence we get
$$\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} \sum_{k\ \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^k}{z-k}e^{i\pi kx}=e^{i\pi z x}.$$
I'm stuck here.

Edit:

If I compute it in $x = 1 $, since $e^{i\pi k}=(-1)^k $ I get

$$\sum_{k\ \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{z-k}= \frac{\pi e^{i\pi z}}{\sin(\pi z)}.$$

Comment: Let $x=0$ then use Parseval's  Equality.  Is this clear?

Comment: Yes! Really, thanks!

Comment: We don't need to compute it in $x =0$ to use Parseval's Equality though...

Comment: my mistake you are right

Comment: If I use Parseval's Equality I obtain $|\sin^2(\pi z)|$ which is different from $\sin^2(\pi z)$. Isn't it?

Comment: you are right, I appologize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107851/discussion-between-nicola-and-guy3141).